# How to get the unselected population in python random module

Tags: python, list, random

So, I know I can get a random list from a population using the random module,

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 ,9]

print(random.sample(l, 3))
# [1, 3, 2]
```

But, how do I get the list of the unselected ones? Do, I need to remove them manually from the list? Or, is there a method to get them too?

Edit: The list l from example doesn't contain the same items multiple times, but when it does I wouldn't want it removed more than it's selected as sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 ,9]
s1 = set(random.sample(l, 3))
s2 = set(l).difference(s1)
```

```
>>> s1
{0, 3, 8}

>>> s2
{1, 2, 4, 9}
```

**Update**: same items multiple times

You can shuffle your list first and partition your population after in two:

```
l = [7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 6, 9, 8, 6, 3, 8]

pop = l[:]
random.shuffle(pop)

pop1, pop2 = pop[:3], pop[3:]
```

```
>>> pop1
[8, 4, 9]

>>> pop2
[7, 6, 8, 6, 5, 6, 9, 6, 5, 8, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Yes! Using shuffle and pop to make the same effect is a clever idea!

Answer (score 2):

Because your list can contain multiple same items, you can change to the approach below:

```py
import random

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 ,9]

random.shuffle(l)
selected = l[:3]
unselected = l[3:]

print(selected)
# [4, 0, 1]
print(unselected)
# [8, 2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: The problem is that the list can contain multiple same items if selected once I would want them removed only once not all of them. And, I can use for loop and list's remove method for that but I was looking if there was already a method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of duplicates, you could count the items of each type and compare the population count to the sample count.

If you don't care about the order of items in the population, you could do it like this:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

population = [1, 1, 2, 2, 9, 7, 9]
sample = random.sample(population, 3)
pop_count = Counter(population)
samp_count = Counter(sample)

unsampled = [
    k 
    for k in pop_count
    for i in range(pop_count[k] - samp_count[k])
]
```

If you care about the order in the population, you could do something like this:

```
check = sample.copy()
unsampled = []
for val in population:
    if val in check:
        check.remove(val)
    else:
        unsampled.append(val)
```

Or there's this weird list comprehension (not recommended):

```
check = sample.copy()
unsampled = [
    x 
    for x in population 
    if x not in check or check.remove(x)
]
```

The `if` clause here uses two tricks:

1. both parts of the test will be `False`ish if `x` is not in `check` (`list.remove()` always returns `None`), and
2. `remove()` will only be called if the first part fails, i.e., if `x` is in `check`.

Basically, if (and only if) `x` is in `check`, it will bomb through and check the next condition, which will also be `False` (`None`), but will have the side effect of removing one copy of `x` from `check`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in this much detail, really appreciate ya.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with:

```
import random

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 ,9]

rand = random.sample(l, 3)
rest = list(set(l) - set(rand))

print(f"initial list: {l}")
print(f"random list: {rand}")
print (f"rest list: {rest}")
```

Result:

```
initial list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
random list: [2, 9, 0]
rest list: [8, 1, 3, 4]
```